# Filtros com PHP - Formulário de Pesquisa

Tags: php, mysql

Como eu poderia fazer um filtro como esse da imagem exemplo?

A parte as tabelas com os dados e `SELECT` para buscar está tranquilo. O que eu estou sofrendo é em como montar o código PHP para isso, talvez alguém tenha uma forma para que eu possa aprender a fazer esses filtros.

Estou aprendendo essa linguagem ainda, já procurei sobre esse assunto mas não encontrei nada muito esclarecedor, principalmente algo que ajude nos primeiros passos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
ESTRUTURA DO BANCO:

    TABELA ATIVIDADES
    -COD_ATIVIDADE
    -CODOPERADOR_ATIVIDADE
    -NOME_ATIVIDADE
    -DATAINICIO_ATIVIDADE
    -DATAFIM_ATIVIDADE
    -STATUS_ATIVIDADE

    TABELA OPERADORES
    -COD_OPERADOR
    -NOME_OPERADOR


    **EXEMPLO DE CÓDIGO DE RESULTADO:**
<?php


session_start();
$Act = $_GET['act'];


if(isset($Act)){

if($Act == "filtraratv"){
$status = trim($_POST['STATUS_ATIVIDADE']);   
$operador = trim($_POST['CODOPERADOR_ATIVIDADE']);
$dataini = $_POST['DATAINICIO_ATIVIDADE'];
$datafim = ($_POST['DATAFIM_ATIVIDADE']);


if(file_exists("../../config.php")) {
    require "../../config.php";     
} else {
    echo "Arquivo config.php nao foi encontrado";
    exit;
}

if(!function_exists("Abre_Conexao")) {
    echo "Erro o arquivo config.php foi auterado, nao existe a função Abre_Conexao";
    exit;
}
Abre_Conexao();
$busca = mysql_query("select * from atividades WHERE status_atividade ='$status'");
$row = mysql_num_rows($busca);
    if ($row==0) {
        echo "Não há dados";
    } 
    else {
        wwhile($l = mysql_fetch_array($busca)) {
            $status   = $l["STATUS_ATIVIDADE"];
            echo "<option value=\"$status\">STATUS: $status</option>\n";
        }
    }


}
}

?>
```

OBS: CÓDIGO DE RETORNO: Quando executa com alguma condição (Filtro) que não satisfaz a pesquisa está exibindo a mensagem que manda exibir:"Nenhum resultado encontrado com esses critérios", porém quando executa uma pesquisa que existe resultado, aparece apenas uma página em branco...

Comment: Seria bom vc colocar a estrutura do banco de dados mysql

Comment: Acabei de colocar as tabelas e campos principais..No filtro de exemplo poderia ter também o campo NOME DA ATIVIDADE.

Comment: Conseguiu fazer?

Comment: O que você tentou fazer?

Comment: Nao consegui,  mas ta tranquilo vou me virar aqui. E quando descobri eu posto o exemplo aqui pra caso alguém precisar, não ficar na mão!

Comment: É muito fácil fazer isto, basta elaborar um SQL para exibição. Com o SQL você consegue fazer o restante?

Comment: @TiagoIB Postei uma resposta, veja se atende sua necessidade.

Comment: @AndréBaill postei o Código de retorno para os filtros, e mesmo assim não funciona (Retorna pagina em branco ou a mensagem de que não foi encontrado nenhum resultado), da uma olhada.

Comment: @AndréBaill Esse jeito está muito errado? Minha última tentativa, se não der vou tentar pesquisar outras formas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui dessa maneira:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
ini_set(“display_errors”, 0 );

$status = isset($_POST['status_atividade']) ? $_POST['status_atividade'] : '';
$operador = isset($_POST['codoperador_atividade']) ? $_POST['codoperador_atividade'] : '';
$dataini1 = isset($_POST['datainicio1_atividade']) ? $_POST['datainicio1_atividade'] : '';
$dataini2 = isset($_POST['datainicio2_atividade']) ? $_POST['datainicio2_atividade'] : '';
$datafim1 = isset($_POST['datafim1_atividade']) ? $_POST['datafim1_atividade'] : '';
$datafim2 = isset($_POST['datafim2_atividade']) ? $_POST['datafim2_atividade'] : '';

if(file_exists("../config.php")) {
    require "../config.php";        
} else {
    echo "Arquivo config.php nao foi encontrado";
    exit;
}

if(!function_exists("Abre_Conexao")) {
    echo "Erro o arquivo config.php foi auterado, nao existe a função Abre_Conexao";
    exit;
}
Abre_Conexao();
    $getatividades = 
    "SELECT * FROM atividades INNER JOIN operadores on cod_operador = codoperador_atividade WHERE cod_atividade > 0 ";

    if (strcmp(trim($status), "") != 0) { 
        $getatividades .= "AND status_atividade = '$status' ";
    }

    if (strcmp(trim($operador), "") != 0) { 
        $getatividades .= "AND codoperador_atividade = '$operador' ";
    }

    //Data Inicial Entre
    if ((strcmp(trim($dataini1), "") != 0) && (strcmp(trim($dataini2), "") != 0)) { 
        $getatividades .= "AND datainicio_atividade between '$dataini1' and '$dataini2' ";
    }
    else if (strcmp(trim($dataini1), "") != 0) { 
        $getatividades .= "AND datainicio_atividade >= '$dataini1' ";
    }
    else if (strcmp(trim($dataini2), "") != 0) { 
        $getatividades .= "AND datainicio_atividade <= '$dataini2' ";
    }

    //Data Fim Entre
    if ((strcmp(trim($datafim1), "") != 0) && (strcmp(trim($datafim2), "") != 0)) { 
        $getatividades .= "AND datafim_atividade between '$datafim1' and '$datafim2' ";
    }
    else if (strcmp(trim($datafim1), "") != 0) { 
        $getatividades .= "AND datafim_atividade >= '$datafim1' ";
    }
    else if (strcmp(trim($datafim2), "") != 0) { 
        $getatividades .= "AND datafim_atividade <= '$datafim2' ";
    }

    //Aqui
    $getatividadesquery = mysql_query($getatividades) or die(mysql_error());
    if (!$getatividadesquery) {
        echo "Não foi possível executar a consulta ($getatividadesquery) no banco de dados: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($getatividadesquery) == 0) {
        echo "Não foram encontradas linhas, nada para mostrar, assim eu estou saindo";
        exit;
    }


    while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($getatividadesquery)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. $linha['STATUS_ATIVIDADE'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $linha['NOME_ATIVIDADE'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $linha['NOME_OPERADOR'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $linha['DATAINICIO_ATIVIDADE'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $linha['DATAFIM_ATIVIDADE'] .'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }



?>
```

Funcionou!!

Comment: Ótimo! Foi bem do jeito que sugeri, só adaptou! :)

Comment: Show de Bola @AndréBaill

Answer (score 4):

De acordo com o banco de dados citado acima, creio eu que seja isso que você gostaria de fazer, conforme for selecionando ou preenchendo os dados, vai montando o SQL para executar.

```
// STATUS
if(isset($_POST['STATUS_ATIVIDADE'])) $STATUS_ATIVIDADE = "AND STATUS_ATIVIDADE = '".$_POST['STATUS_ATIVIDADE']."'"; else $STATUS_ATIVIDADE = "";

// OPERADOR
if(isset($_POST['COD_OPERADOR'])) $COD_OPERADOR = "AND CODOPERADOR_ATIVIDADE = '".$_POST['CODOPERADOR_ATIVIDADE']."'"; else $COD_OPERADOR = "";

// DATA_INICIO
if(isset($_POST['DATA_INICIOATIVIDADE'])) $DATA_INICIOATIVIDADE = "AND DATA_INICIOATIVIDADE = '".$_POST['DATA_INICIOATIVIDADE']."'"; else $DATA_INICIOATIVIDADE = "";

// DATA_FIM
if(isset($_POST['DATA_FIMATIVIDADE'])) $DATA_FIMATIVIDADE = "AND DATA_FIMATIVIDADE = '".$_POST['DATA_FIMATIVIDADE']."'"; else $DATA_FIMATIVIDADE = "";

// CONSULTA

$SQL = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        ATIVIDADES AS C1
    WHERE 
        C1.COD_ATIVIDADE != '' 
        {$STATUS_ATIVIDADE} 
        {$COD_OPERADOR} 
        {$DATA_INICIOATIVIDADE} 
        {$DATA_FIMATIVIDADE}
") or print mysql_error();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "Atividade: ".$row['NOME_ATIVIDADE']."<br>";   
}
```

Tente elaborar dessa forma.

Comment: Sim, é por ai mesmo. Vou tentar aqui pra ver, mas é nesse sentido onde conforme as opções será o resultado mostrado.

Comment: Ok, sem problemas, Faça o teste. qualquer coisa questione.

Comment: Postei o Código de retorno para os filtros, e mesmo assim não funciona (Retorna pagina em branco ou a mensagem de que não foi encontrado nenhum resultado), da uma olhada.

Comment: Não dá pra usar na mesma query, fazendo que nem tu fez de colocar AND x AND y... tem que ir adicionando conforme eu te mostrei no exemplo, pra que o scritp entenda qual campo foi preenchido

Comment: O que eu preciso repetir é a parta da consulta apenas?

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi, você quer mostrar os dados buscados.

Vamos a uma possível resposta:

```
$busca=mysql_query("select * from Atividades");
$row = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($row==0) {
    echo "Não há dados";
} else {
    while ($dados = mysql_fect_array($query) {
        echo "Nome: ". $dados['nomeDocampoNaTabelaAtividades'];
    }
}
```

Você quer filtrar os dados, como por exemplo: ordenar por id, nome, etc. Isso então seria paginação.

Ou você quer apenas retornar todos os dados num array e exibir ao seu modo? Por exemplo, exibir por lista, tabela, etc.

Na verdade, ainda não entendi.

Comment: Isso, seria em forma de lista. Apenas exibir o resultado.